# How do I recursively remove temporary files containing ~ in git repositories

Tags: git, recursion

I have committed a large number of files and folders to a git repository, but realized all of the temporary files ending in ~ have also been committed. I would like to remove these recursively.  I have tried

```
git rm -r *~
```

Unfortunately this does not look through each subfolder to remove these files.

What is missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote the glob to let git (rather than your shell) expand it.

```
git rm '*~'
```

Note that you don't need `-r` in this case. (All `...~` are temporary *files*, you are not looking to remove directories and their contents which is what `-r` is all about.)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

> -r
>   Allow recursive removal when a leading directory name is given.

Based on this, you may have to explicitly list the leading directory to perform a recursive remove.

Answer (score 0):

The glob "*~" only expands to file names in the current directory. But you can use the Unix find command to find the files that you are looking for, and use backticks to pass the output of find to git.

```
git rm `find . -name "*~"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unix `find` and `xargs` commands to accomplish tasks like this:

```
find -name '*~' | xargs git rm
```

(If your file names contain could potentially contain newline characters you should also look at the `-print0` option of `find` and the `-0` option of `xargs`.)

Note that this will remove the temporary files from your computer as well! Use `--cached` to only remove the files from git. Also you might want to run with the `--dry-run` option first to make sure you aren't about to delete anything important.